# How do I import d3 (v4) into typescript in an ASP.NET MVC Application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typescript, d3.js

I've built an ASP.NET MVC Application in Visual Studio 2015 and included several javascript libraries. The most important next to jquery is d3 (v4 and partially v3 on some pages).
Now I dig into Typescript (it's pretty new to me).

Before I get into details, here's my question: What is the easiest way to switch from JS to TS and how do I deal with moment.js, d3.js and other dependencies?

Unfortunately I am not able to include the d3 module into my .ts file. It says "Cannot find module d3" if trying to include it by `import * as d3 from 'd3';`

I've also tried to use the type definition files, by loading them manually into the project and by downloading it via npm (`npm install @types/d3 --save-dev`). None of them worked. Probably I am misunderstanding how it works or should work.

Right after this problem is fixed I will have to deal with AMD or CommonJS as well. Could you suggest an easy solution which does not require several additional installs to my project?

Thanks a lot in advance and sorry if I wasn't precise enough (it's my first question on SO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `import * as d3 from 'd3';` you're requiring the d3 package that is only available locally in your `node_modules` and therefore will not work in a browser. That's were dependency blunders (such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)) come in place, they read all required packages by your code and include them in your build output. However, since you said you're new to Node.js and TypeScript I must warn you that configuring a project using these tools can be quite difficult and the learning curve is rather steep. Make a research on your project needs and if you see that you'll need it at some point, start learning how to use webpack ASAP, since adapting your code later on can be even more painful.

Another option would be to include jQuery and D3.js in the old fashioned way (with normal script tags). In this scenario, to make TypeScript recognize jQuery and D3 even when they're are loaded separately we use what we call "ambient declarations". Those declarations expose the definitions under global variables of these libraries so TypeScript assumes that a global `d3` or a `$` variable will be available at run time and will hold the API of the libraries that we want. Therefore no `import` is needed.

Thankfully both "@types/jquery" and "@types/d3" already include these global declarations. For D3 make sure you're installing the definitions for v4 with `npm i --save-dev @types/d3@4.x`

Another steps that may be required for using vanilla dependencies are some tweaks on your [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) file. Here's an example:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "classic",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "d3",
      "jquery"
    ]
  }
}
```

Pay attention to `module` and `moduleResolution` and [pick the options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) that better suits you. Also note the `types` option making TypeScript include the ambient declarations from `@types/d3` and `@types/jquery`. Those options are for TypeScript 2.0 by the way.

Honestly its hard for me to say what exactly what you need to do to get everything working since each context requires different setups. But I hope that I at least got you in the right direction to figure out the rest by yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Hi snolflake, thank you very much for taking your time, to help me. Indeed you pushed me into the right direction and made lots of aspects clearer. Thanks to you it's up and running =). Thanks a lot!